# Traduirait-on « meltdown » en « fusion » tout court ou autrement ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, choix-de-mot

> Can you operate the historic Chernobyl Nuclear Power Plant (RBMK-1000)
> without causing a Meltdown?

...*faire fonctionner... sans causer de/un(e)/le-la*... ?

En anglais le mot [*meltdown*](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/meltdown) signifie [*nuclear metldown*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_meltdown) soit la [*fusion du coeur d'un réacteur nucléaire*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusion_du_c%C5%93ur_d%27un_r%C3%A9acteur_nucl%C3%A9aire), mais aussi essentiellement un « effondrement » qui s'apparenterait au figuré du moins à une catastrophe pour l'essentiel.

Ici le contexte est évidemment la simulation, mais en ce qui a trait à *fusion du coeur d'un réacteur nucléaire*, choisirait-on de l'employer au long ; *fusion* tout court serait-il compris, usuel ; choisirait-on de traduire différemment et pourquoi ?

Answer (score 5):

*[...] sans causer une/la fusion du coeur.*

Dans ce contexte, *une* et *la* peuvent convenir. On peut utiliser *une* si on veut parler du de l'événement de fusion du coeur en général, mais *la* est aussi approprié car on parle de la fusion du coeur de ce réacteur précis. De plus, *la* implique que cet événement est irréversible.

Dans le nucléaire, on parle de *fusion du coeur* (plus courant), *fusion du réacteur* (strictement moins correct) ou *fusion du coeur du réacteur*.
*Fusion* tout court n'est pas assez spécifique, sauf si on précise que *le coeur entre en fusion* ou qu'*il y a une fusion du coeur du réacteur*, par exemple.

A ne surtout pas traduire par *fusion nucléaire*, qui est le procédé dans lequel on fusionne les atomes au lieu de les fissionner, comme on a pu le voir dans des articles sur l'accident de Fukushima.

Comment: ta remarque est très intéressante, on peut avoir une fusion (accidentelle) du coeur dans un réacteur à fission, ce qui signifie simplement qu'en raison d'un problème de refroidissement il monte en température jusqu'à sa température de fusion (autour de 3000°C). Cela n'entraîne pas d'explosion, et c'est ce qui s'est passé à Chernobyl et à Fukushima. Les explosions qui ont eu lieu étaient liées à de l'hydrogène qui s'était formé indirectement, mais ne sont pas des explosions nucléaires. Il s'agit donc de fusion dans le sens "fondre".

Comment: Par opposition aux centrales à fusion, où ce terme se rapporte au fait de "fusionner" des atomes pour en former d'autres, tout en dégageant de l'énergie. C'est amusant qu'en français ce soit le même terme "fusion" pour les deux concepts, alors qu'en anglais les termes "meltdown" et "fusion" sont bien distincts. Tout au plus peut-on comme tu l'indiques spécifier "fusion du coeur" ou "fusion nucléaire" selon le cas, et surtout sans les confondre.